# SqlCeException was caught

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

After executing my Sql code i get the following error. I have been trying for a hours and i cant seem to find where the error is.

> There was an error parsing the query.
>   [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 170,Token in error = Plan ]

```sql
SELECT [Serial Number] , Type , Model , [Activation Date] , IMEI , 
    [Phone Number] , [Fax Number] , [Data Number] , PIN1 , PUK1 , 
    PIN2 , PUK2 , IMSI , ICCID , Provider , Plan 
FROM [FBB Terminals] 
WHERE [Vessel Name] = 'AAL Salamina'
```

[Here is a picture of the table if this helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jThd7.png)

Comment: `Plan` is a [reserved word in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix You should add that as an answer.